# R - Auth into BigQuery from Google Compute Engine without Service Account Keys

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-compute-engine, rstudio-server

We currently use a service account json key to access BigQuery from RStudio non-interactively. But as you may know, there are inherent security issues that come with this method i.e. Anyone with the key on any machine can access BigQuery using this method. So I was wondering, is there a way we can access BigQuery data in RStudio only if it is coming from a particular compute engine instance in GCP? Does google offer a way to auth via compute engine without any keys? If so, how can I use the same via RStudio non-interactively?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with RStudio. Google provides key-less auth if the app (RStudio in this case) supports Application Default Credentials. In this case, the app can acquire the VM's credentials from the metadata service. Another, new key-less feature is Workload Identity for the case where RStudio is running atop GKE. There are likely other ways.

Comment: @DazWilkin Hey, thanks for replying. I looked into getting ADC and was able to use the temporary tokens that we get from metadata service to auth into BigQuery via RStudio. The only concern I have now is, that the tokens are temporary. I noticed they have a timeout of ~ 1 hour. What if we have an app runs for more than an hour? In that case would it just fail to get data from BQ after an hour?

Comment: Yes, any requests made after expiration will fail. You will need to refresh the token before then. ADC would provide this functionality but I assume you're unable to leverage it with RStudio. If you're able to do so, you should be able to use Google's Token Service to exchange tokens. Google appears to have hidden the URL to the Token Service with the identity toolkit stuff.

Comment: @DazWilkin I am able to use the ADC service, but our scripts are setup such that at the beginning of the script, we authenticate, then the rest of the operations of BQ run. In this case, if a script runs more than an hour, I assume it will fail after that. Is there a solution which doesn't use token keys in such scenarios?

Comment: @DazWilkin TO be more clear, from google's docs

1) If the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is set, ADC uses the service account key or configuration file that the variable points to.

2) If the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS isn't set, ADC uses the service account that is attached to the resource that is running your code.
I am using point 2 here since point 1 involves using a key, which is inherently insecure as anyone can copy and use it on another machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update 20220105 :

You can simply set the below option at the beginning of the script or via [.Rprofile](https://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html) to automatically set this up on startup

`options(gargle.gce.timeout = 2)`

Note - In case of Ubuntu, full path of Rprofile.site is `/usr/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site`

##########################Old Content#########################

Update - I was able to perform keyless auth using application direct credentials as DazWilkin had pointed out. But doing so was not straight forward. bigrquery's bq_auth() function uses the gargle package for authentication. gargle has a function called credentials_gce() to auth using service accounts. In theory, when in a compute engine whose service account has access to BQ, bq_auth() would call credentials_gce() and auth should just work seamlessly, without any additional parameters. But in practice, as of v1.2.0 of gargle, I've found a bug. gargle has a default timeout of 0.8 set for getting temporary token from google's metadata server, which is too low such that it times out even before it can receive a legitimate request from google's internal metadata service. As of now, I've found that adding below lines before bq_auth() solves the problem. Infact, you don't need to write bq_auth() separately as bigrquery will automatically run bq_auth() the moment it finds an operation that requires authentication, but I've found that in some cases when combined with googleCloudStorageR package, bq_auth() doesn't work as expected so I've added it separately.

```
library(gargle)
library(bigrquery)

invisible(
  try({
  httr::with_config(httr::timeout(getOption("gargle.gce.timeout", default = 2)), {
    httr::GET('http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token', httr::add_headers("Metadata-Flavor" = "Google"))
    })
  },
  silent = TRUE)
)

bq_auth()
```

As an additional note, if someone is looking on how to do the same with googleCloudStorageR, the R package to interact with Google Cloud Storage, the code goes as follows. Note that googleCloudStorageR uses the googleAuthR package for authentication. Calling gcs_auth() separately won't be needed.

```
library(googleAuthR)

invisible(
  try({
  httr::with_config(httr::timeout(getOption("gargle.gce.timeout", default = 2)), {
    httr::GET('http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token', httr::add_headers("Metadata-Flavor" = "Google"))
    })
  },
  silent = TRUE)
)

gar_gce_auth(
  scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery",
  service_account = "default"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Is there a way we can access BigQuery data in RStudio only if it is coming from a particular compute engine instance in GCP?**

According with the GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication) in matters of Big Query, there are 3 ways to authenticate your clients for use Big query API

- Service account (when you are using service account you can also use
  [Key file](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file) or [Default credentials](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/getting-started))
- [User accounts](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/end-user-installed) (Use user credentials to ensure that your
  application has access only to BigQuery tables that are available to
  the end user)
- And [authorizing API request](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization) (passing an access token to the
  BigQuery API so that it knows your client is authorized to access the
  requested resources)

**Does google offer a way to auth via compute engine without any keys?**

Yes, there are a few options to authorize applications without using keys, using authentication.

> If you use the Compute Engine API to manage your Compute Engine
> resources, you can authenticate your applications to the API by
> obtaining credentials from a Compute Engine service account. Service
> accounts let your application authenticate to the API without
> embedding any secret keys in your application code.

You can authorize *Applications that run in Compute Engine Instances, Applications that run outside Google cloud and applications that are in development,* in [this Document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/how-tos/authorization) you will find guides with detailed explanations about how these options work.

Regarding your question: **how can I use the same via RStudio non-interactively?**

I am not sure if I completely understand the meaning of your question: if your Question is oriented to use Authentication settings for Rstudio [in this document](https://docs.rstudio.com/connect/1.7.6/admin/authentication.html) you will find more information about this  topic.
In the Rstudio page I found this options, it is worth to take a look at it closely:

- [SAML Single Sign-On Authentication](https://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/authenticating_users/saml_sso.html)
- [OpenID Connect Authentication](https://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/authenticating_users/openid_connect_authentication.html)
- [Google Accounts](https://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/authenticating_users/google_accounts.html)